# Why did wounded Jim visit Chuck Barris at night?

Tags: plot-explanation, confessions-of-a-dangerous-mind

In [*Confessions of a Dangerous Mind*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0270288/) based on the Chuck Barris (author of the "Dating Game" TV show) autobiography, we find that he was a part-time CIA hitman. One night, he notices that his supervisor Jim Byrd is sitting near his pool. They have a heated conversation where Jim says that they have a mole in a cell that has already killed other agents. Then the camera pans away and we see that Jim is heavily bleeding.

Fragment of this scene can be found on youtube:

I am  a bit confused about this scene: why did wounded Jim come to see Chuck instead of seeking help? Was he there to kill Chuck (as he could be the mole)? How couldn't Chuck notice (they have quite a long heated discussion) that Jim is bleeding in the first place? Was that scene even real or was it some sort of a vision?